# One class for two different deserializations

Tags: java, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a request for two or more different websites. I'm trying to get some data from them and save it to the database. They are basically having the same model of response but with the different names of the JSON fields.
As I know, I can't add more than one `@JsonProperty` to the field.

First, that came to mind is to create two classes `WebOneResponse` and `WebTwoResponse` with `@JsonProperty` annotation's values that I need, use them for requests to different websites and then parse all of them to some `BaseClass` that then will be inserted into the database and used inside the application for analysis. (`BaseClass`, in that case, must have some id that will tell which one of the websites did it came from)

And in that case, I can't even extend any of ****Response from the `BaseClass` because of annotations. And it becomes very messy.

What is the best practice in that case?

Comment: I will make separate endpoints as you are inherently sending different Model. However the common code can be refactored.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds fair and quite normal approach. Additionally i would either create `BaseClassFactory` that can convert `WebOneResponse` and `WebTwoResponse` to  `BaseClass`, or add `toBaseClass` methods to each response. However factory approach seems more elegant.